# Years of seasons from dates in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

There is an array with a body part and dates. What should a formula look like that **splits it first by body parts, and then by the condition** (the interval between each next date is no more than 30 days for each body part) into groups, and **then outputs the years that are within that group**?

For example, there are 6 groups of dates. For each group I need to output the years that are within this group (for example, if there are two years 2022 and 2023, then output 22/23, if there is only one 2021, then this year + 1, we get 21/22)
[image]
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Haqs37snvnBUyGO8quwfpp-nGIMOaTdgyW1S7V3rUdg/edit#gid=0

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data, to avoid closure of the question. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: Within your expected output scenario; is the first group o/p supposed to be `22/23` OR `23/24`?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
=let(Σ;{1;scan(1;B3:index(B:B;match(;0/(B:B<>"")));lambda(a;c;if(isbetween(days(c;offset(c;-1;));0;30)*(offset(c;;-1)=offset(c;-1;-1));a;a+1)))};
       map(Σ;lambda(Γ;let(Λ;text(minifs(B2:index(B:B;match(;0/(B:B<>"")));Σ;Γ);"y");Λ&"/"&Λ+1))))
```

- *group_1 output is kinda `mismatching` with your expected output*

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are right, excuse me. Is it possible to fix this formula, if there is only 1 year (for example 23), then output 1, if 2, then 2 (for example 22/23)? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Haqs37snvnBUyGO8quwfpp-nGIMOaTdgyW1S7V3rUdg/edit#gid=0